# Get json from code behind file in asp.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I have a webstatic method which converts my dataset into json and i want that json in my javascript file but i am getting nothing in my div here . What i am doing wrong here as i am new to asp.net and json . 
The simple task which i have to perform here is to get my json from code behind file to javascript .

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#Result").click(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "A2_JVV.aspx/ds2json",
                     data: "{}",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (msg) {
                         $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                     }

                 });
             });
         });

     </script>
```

in my A2_JVV.aspx.cs page I have use Newton json to convert my dataset in json

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string ds2json()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds=(DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["dsgrr"];
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables["jv"], Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

Chrome Console error

```
    POST http://localhost:49388/WebSite2/A2_JVV.aspx/ds2json 500 (Internal Server Error)
c.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130(anonymous function)
 @ A2_JVV.aspx:207c.event.handle
 @ jquery-1.4.2.min.js:55c.event.add.j.handle.o 
@ jquery-1.4.2.min.js:49
```

Comment: Are you getting in the Network tab {"d":null} in chrome console?

Comment: Try checking this line: ds=(DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["dsgrr"]. Something is wrong in there.

Comment: put a breakpoint in your webmethod... See if some error is occurring there?

Comment: WebMehtod is working fine .

Comment: ds=(DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["dsgrr"]. this line is working perfect and i have checked it with Breakpoint @Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez

Comment: Response.Write(ds2json()); it works perfect in code behind then why it is not working in my javascript .

Comment: I have come up with a solution that ds was returning me rows 9500 i have tried another ds.Table which is returning only two rows and the method is working fine is there some kind of limit or anything like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are not calling the right method.

```
$.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "A2_JVV.aspx/ds2json",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (msg) {
                         var result = $.JSON(msg);
                         $("#Result").text(result.d);
                     }

                 });
```

Comment: @meraname are you getting any javascript errors? And what is msg.d? is "d" a field in json response?

Comment: I am not getting any error the div text remains the same as it is .

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to add "/" at first of url :

```
url: "/A2_JVV.aspx/ds2json"
```

Comment: There is an internal error in ds2json function, you need to debug the code to see what is the error.

Comment: There is one more thing, can you please move the script to be outside the update panel,  you can put it in the header or after the body

Comment: I have put my script outside the update panel after sciptManager but getting the same error .

Comment: I don't know if there is a conflict between Jquery and  ajaxtoolkit (Upate Panel), so if you can put the div of result outside the the panel. and try to call your method again. usually we don't use Jquery with Ajaxtool kit. if i have update panel i don't need for ajax call. so just try to take the result div outside the update panel

Comment: I have come up with a solution that ds was returning me rows 9500 i have tried another ds.Table which is returning only two rows and the method is working fine is there some kind of limit or anything like that ? –